# How do I create multiple C++ threads without blocking the main thread using join()?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a simple TCP client/server in C++ and I am currently spawning a thread per connected user to handle messages, however I have run into a few issues and I'm not sure how to solve them as I am unfamiliar with the standard C++ threading.

When a client connects to the server, a thread is created for that client until they are disconnected using something like

```
clientThread = thread(processMessages);
clientThread.join();
```

This thread will persist for the lifetime of the client. As I have called join() on this thread, when **client 2** connects while **client 1** is still connected, it is blocked by the join() call.

Removing this join() call means that when a client disconnects, the thread is destroyed causing a **terminate()** error due to it being joinable.

How can I make this client thread just process in the background while the main thread can just continue and accept new connections?

Comment: use `detach()` instead of `join()`.

Comment: Oh wow thanks, completely missed this.

Comment: I refrain to recommend [`thread::detach()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) :-/. [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) may be better advice.

Comment: Using `detach` in this situation is a little like advising that somebody cut off their arms to prevent mosquito bites. The big problem here is the "spawning a thread per connected user", which is well known to work poorly. My advice would be to look up something like ASIO that can handle your problem in a reasonably sensible, scalable manner. If you really want to do it on your own, create a pool of threads and a queue of requests to be handled by the thread pool. This can reduce overhead a lot.

Comment: If you are joining immediately after creation, then there isn't much point in making a thread in the first place. If you are making a new `thread`, you presumably want to do work in parallel or asynchronously. So do whatever it is you need the main thread to do while the worker thread works and only `join` with it when you actually need to know that the `thread` is done.

Comment: _I am currently spawning a thread per connected user_ No!  Have a look at  [ASIO](https://think-async.com/Asio) standalone or Boost variants will do what you want.

Comment: There's no need to join the thread immediately, because the main thread should be in a loop `accept`ing connections.

Comment: Just move the `join()` call until after everything else `main()` needs to do.

Answer (score 3):

Just showing how you can store created `thread` objects:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.emplace_back(processMessages);
...
for (auto & t : threads) t.join();
```

However, as others pointed out in comments, creating a thread for each new connection might not be the best approach.